# How to retrieve the Image path from carousal that is displayed in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a share button which should share the image file that is displayed in carousal.
How can I retrieve the image file path from the carousal that is displayed?
Image are mapped like below :

```
   class ImgView extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<Item> mItems;
      final String title;
      ImageView({this.mItems, @required this.title, Key key})
```

Widget body is build like below:

```
  body: mItems.length == 1
      ? Center(child: Image.file(File(mItems[0].path)))
      : Carousel(
    images: mItems
        .map((MediaItem item) => FileImage(File(item.path)))
        .toList(growable: false),
  ),
);
```

}
}

```
_sendEmail() async {
        try {

//here I just hard coded the first image file path but i couldn't pass values which are currently displaying in Carousal
    final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(firstfileimagepath);
          await Share.file(
              'esys image', mediaItems[0].title+getFileExtensionFromPath(firstfileimagepath) , bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png',
              text: 'My optional text.');
        } catch (e) {
          throw 'Some message';
        }
      }
  
    }
```

Comment: You can access the path from your map. What is the problem?

Comment: Share full code, its not possible to tell what is the actual issue without seeing the full code.

Comment: I have added the full code please please see the code

Comment: I have answered your question, let me know if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using this [carousel](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_pro) package.

The carousel package provides us with a property which is a function named `onImageChang` This function passed the previous and current image index as an argument and then you can use the index provided by this function to share your image.

```dart
int index = 0;

 body: mediaItems.length == 1
      ? Center(child: Image.file(File(mediaItems[0].path)))
      : Carousel(
    autoplay: false,
    boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
    indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
    dotSize: 4.0,
    onImageChange: (prev,current) {
      setState(() {
          index = current;
      });
    },
    images: mediaItems
        .map((MediaItem item) => FileImage(File(item.path)))
        .toList(growable: false),
  ),
);

// now you can use your index to get the current image index and use that to share images.

final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(mediaItems[index].path);
      await Share.file(
          'esys image', mediaItems[index].title+getFileExtensionFromPath(mediaItems[index].path) , bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png',
          text: 'My optional text.');
    } catch (e) {
      throw 'Could not send mail or no default mail application is present';
    }
  }
  String getFileExtensionFromPath(String path) {
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my Widget is stateless and I am getting error at setState() Is there any way to solve this I tried to make my Widget stateful but still the error is there .
Sorry for asking these questions I have very basic knowledge of flutter

Comment: just convert your stateless widget to stateful and this will work. what is the error you are getting after converting it into a stateful widget?

Comment: @Nban Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222962/how-to-change-from-stateless-widget-to-stateful-widget.

Comment: It says that the method setState () is not defined for ImgView

Comment: @NBan check the link I shared and convert your class into a stateful widget and you will be good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help you saved me